# Regex expression to find words where you know the alphabetical order of the letters but not the letters?

Tags: python, regex

This is a hard question to word, but if you have the word: `'apple'`. Alphabetically, its letters would be listed `['a','e','l','p','p']`

So if you assign `1` to `'a'`, `2` to `'e'`, etc, you know the word's letters follow this pattern: `14532`.

So I'm trying to think of how to make a regex that will search for words where the letters follow that order. This could even be a python script, I only need to do this once for ~1m words.

EDIT for more clarity:

Using the above system, and given a number, ie, '14532' return all words from a given list which follow that alphabetical pattern.

Comment: What have you tried up to now and how did it go?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using a regex?

Comment: Why do you think regex will be useful here? Do you have a list of possible valid words, or could you use a standard word list, eg a list of words that are legal in Scrabble?

Comment: Using the English [SOWPODS](http://www.3zsoftware.com/download/) wordlist, and the `(1, 4, 5, 3, 2)` pattern, here are some of the words I found AGUED AILED AIMED AIRED AJUGA ALOED ALOHA ALPHA AMNIA AMNIC AMOLE AMPLE ANOLE ANTED ANTIC APPLE APRON APTED ARSON ARTIC ASYLA ATTIC BIKED BILGE BINGE BIPED BLOKE BLUED BLUID BOOED BOONG BORED BORIC BORNE BOUGE BOULE BOUND BOVID BOWED BOWNE BOXED BOYED BRULE BRUME BUXOM CITED CLOKE CLUED COOED COPED CORED CORNI COSEC COSED COSIE COTED COULD COVED COWED COXED COYED COZED COZIE DIKED DINED DINGE DIRGE DITED DIVED DOOLE DOPED DOSED DOTED DOVED

Comment: No reason for using a regex other than not doing more than I need to. Python works fine too. And @PM2Ring, I'm just looking for more of the algorithm and how you would do it rather than the actual words

Comment: You need to improve the question if you want it re-opened. Specifically, you need to post your own attempt at writing some relevant code. FWIW, the code I used to create that word list has a function that uses a dictionary to convert a word like 'APPLE' to the index `(1, 4, 5, 3, 2)` tuple. I then used that function to load a word list into a dictionary, with the index tuple as the key and the corresponding value being a list of words that match that tuple. It takes about 12 seconds to construct that dictionary from the SOWPODS file on my old machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a cute little brain teaser.

```
def char_order(word):
    ascii_values = [ord(letter) for letter in word]
    order_mapping = dict(zip(sorted(set(ascii_values)), xrange(1,len(set(ascii_values))+1)))
    return [order_mapping[value] for value in ascii_values]
```

1. convert the characters in the word to their ascii values
2. map each unique ascii value in the word to an index
3. return the indexes for each character in the word.

> char_order('apple')
>
> > [1, 4, 4, 3, 2]

Comment: Except that in the OP's system, 'apple' maps to `14532`

Comment: And 15432 would be equally acceptable. That's faulty function logic.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I can loop through my list and generate this list for each word and check if it's what I'm looking for. I was thinking of doing it the opposite direction by starting with the number list and then somehow finding words that matched it.

Comment: One person's homework is another person's brain teaser.

Comment: @chilypepper Why is `[1, 4, 4, 3, 2]` acceptable? I thought you wanted 'APPLE' to map to `(1, 4, 5, 3, 2)`? FWIW, this trnsformation is simpler than the one specified in the question, and possibly more useful because it results in less matches.

Comment: 1. What's the point of `ascii_values = [ord(letter) for letter in word]`? You can word directly with the letters instead of their `ord`s. 2. Creating the same set twice is inefficient. 3. You could use `enumerate` instead of zipping with a range.